# ReactJS methods on mount

Tags: reactjs

Recently I took an online test where the following question was asked:

Which of the following methods is not executed while mounting a React Component?

1. constructor()
2. render()
3. componentWillReceiveProps()
4. componentDidMount()

I believe all of these methods will get executed while mounting a React Component. But I did select option 4. componentDidMount() even though it is wrong as I had to select an option and yes the online test said it is wrong.  [According to an article on Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-execute-javascript-after-reactjs-render-method-has-completed) all of the above methods will execute on mounting (componentWillReceiveProps() is deprecated and static getDerivedStateFromProps() should be used).

What I do not understand is

1. Is the question wrong?
2. Are the options wrong?
3. My understanding of the question is wrong?

I am confused. Please help me get the right perspective.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thanks for the clarification. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) says

> is invoked before a mounted component receives new props.

It operates on a already mounted component receiving **new** props. A component being mounted cannot receive new props until it has initial props.

Also note that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not a 1 for 1 replacement method. It is suggested as an alternative for operations that were typically done in `componentWillReceiveProps`, but they do not do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Phases of React Life Cycle methods

**Mounting**

- constructor
- static getDerivedStateFromProps()
- render()
- componentDidMount()

**Updating**

- static getDerivedStateFromProps()
- shouldComponentUpdate()
- render()
- getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()
- componentDidUpdate()

**unmounting**

- componentWillUnmount()

You can check the official documentation for a better understanding - [the-component-lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)